# Разметка страницы CSS

Tags: веб-программирование, html, css

Делаю сайт, хочется, чтобы блоки (1,2) были зафиксированы, а блок 3 был с прокруткой
 (https://pp.vk.me/c614719/v614719543/1ccae/RjgviyZ3MeE.jpg).

Подскажите, как это реализовать можно, пытался сделать, но у меня во время прокрутки 3 блок выходит за пределы (https://pp.vk.me/c614719/v614719543/1ccb7/Rdm2ReuC8ss.jpg).
Также надо, чтобы, когда блок 3 и блок 2 сравняются снизу, прокрутка остановилась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/k9jh91go/

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family:'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
aside {
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: #7E8BA6;
    float: left;
}
section {
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    min-height: 400px;
}
header {
    background: #2F4162;
    height: 70px;
}
article {
    background: #29D8DE;
    height: 330px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <aside>
        1
    </aside>
    <section>
        <header>2</header>
        <article>            
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut rhoncus nisl sit amet elit vehicula dictum. Nunc in lacinia nisi. Praesent vitae diam est. Fusce porttitor diam enim, quis imperdiet nisi interdum consectetur. Nunc dignissim, quam et tincidunt sagittis, leo nulla fermentum sem, nec eleifend lacus libero non tortor. Morbi dignissim nulla est, vitae consequat erat dignissim ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed vel pharetra nisl. Nam nec lacus nec leo pulvinar rutrum. Mauris turpis est, ultrices at tortor non, mattis iaculis tortor. Vestibulum dapibus neque neque, id viverra risus pretium sit amet. Phasellus rutrum eleifend tellus ut semper. Quisque leo tortor, pellentesque sollicitudin venenatis in, bibendum eu ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. 

 Pellentesque sit amet ipsum tellus. Quisque malesuada fringilla sem, vel tristique tellus consequat nec. Nam vitae risus dolor. Aliquam imperdiet quam at felis vehicula pellentesque. Proin sodales ultricies mauris, sed tincidunt velit scelerisque nec. Phasellus vestibulum vel dolor ac volutpat. Praesent vestibulum mi vitae nulla suscipit, sit amet sagittis nibh convallis. 

 Aliquam at convallis purus. Phasellus at ultrices leo, vel pretium enim. Cras viverra gravida dui a finibus. Phasellus a massa sagittis nunc aliquam condimentum volutpat eget diam. Integer ut lacus auctor, ullamcorper augue vel, euismod massa. Suspendisse elementum condimentum lorem nec sollicitudin. Praesent consequat interdum augue, ac pharetra tortor molestie et. Ut consequat egestas lectus at viverra. Vivamus scelerisque erat sagittis elit viverra, sed semper mi lacinia. Vestibulum tempor vitae nulla id sollicitudin. Mauris vitae bibendum nibh. 

 Donec velit metus, vestibulum sit amet felis dapibus, venenatis ornare eros. Curabitur nec felis quis lorem sodales eleifend. Sed ac dui ultrices, posuere mauris et, egestas arcu. In lacinia hendrerit dolor. Nam ac rhoncus sapien. Nullam tristique eu erat non rutrum. Vestibulum in mattis arcu. Integer volutpat diam diam, nec condimentum massa porta non. Integer accumsan erat tortor, nec pellentesque justo posuere ac. 

 Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ultrices viverra volutpat. Maecenas ac risus tincidunt, facilisis mauris eu, volutpat sapien. Donec maximus dolor nec sapien ullamcorper ultricies. Suspendisse enim quam, dapibus ac eros vel, efficitur molestie velit. Etiam sagittis lobortis laoreet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus elementum condimentum malesuada. Etiam finibus ex non accumsan pellentesque. Pellentesque fringilla, erat ac finibus placerat, neque risus laoreet tortor, ut scelerisque enim massa eu neque. Integer mollis orci vel mauris molestie vestibulum. Vestibulum vestibulum, nibh non ornare hendrerit, odio elit ultrices ligula, nec mollis turpis enim bibendum ex. Sed finibus eros ut mauris condimentum varius. Praesent orci tellus, aliquet eu vestibulum sit amet, imperdiet sit amet urna.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте котнейнер div и css свойство ***overflow*** и почитайте 
[эту статью](http://tradebenefit.ru/element-div-s-prokrutkoi).